# 'acr purge --untagged' is removing all tagged images from an ACR repository

Tags: azure-container-registry

If I have the following tags and manifest in an ACR repository...

[image]

Which returns the following when I run the following command...

```
az acr repository show-manifests --name "[registry-name]" --repository "[repository-name]"
```

```
[
  {
    "digest": "sha256:30be2b07e723b0f36fed370c386b027e52dbcd0ad2ad2fcac1d3b7d1b361292f",
    "tags": [
      "982878",
      "master"
    ],
    "timestamp": "2022-09-07T15:49:04.4187041Z"
  }
]
```

When I run the following purge command....

```
az acr run --cmd "acr purge --filter '[repository-name]:.*' --untagged --ago 1m" --registry [registry-name] /dev/null
```

It is deleting the tags and manifest, and because it deletes everything the repository is deleted as well.

[image]

Why is it doing this when I'm using the `--untagged` flag and you can clearly see it's not untagged based on the starting state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the same in my environment
I have two repositories **`,hello-world with 1 tag: latest`**
[image]

I checked with below command which you tried:

```
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'hello-world:.*' \
--untagged –ago 1m"

az acr run \
  --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" \
  --registry myregistry807 \
  /dev/null
```

It is deleting even the tagged repository

[image]

This command:

```
az acr run --cmd "acr purge --filter 'hello-world:.*' --untagged  --ago 1d" --registry myregistry807 /dev/null
```

It is deleting the tags first, and then it is deleting the untagged manifests and then the registry.

You can check this  [Purge tags and manifests-run-in-an-on-demand-task - Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge#run-in-an-on-demand-task):

> ***This purge command  deletes all image tags and manifests in the
> repository (hello-world in my case) repository in myregistry that were
> modified more than 1 day ago and all the untagged manifests.***

- ***You can try below commands to delete untagged repositories: Commands
  from [Delete all untagged manifests within a repository in one
  command · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/105) where you can use `[?tags[0]==null]` to delete
  only repos with no tag or null tag.***

**In bash:**

```
az acr repository show-manifests -n myregistry807 –repository targetrepository --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv | xargs -I% az acr repository delete -n myregistry807 -t targetrepository @% --yes
```

**for preview version:**

```
az acr manifest  list-metadata  -r  myregistry807 -n hello-world --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv | xargs -I% az acr repository delete -n myregistry807 -t hello-world@% --yes
```

[image]

***and repository is not deleted as it has tags.***

then i checked with `[?tags[0]!=null]` to delete all tags except null, and it successfully worked for me:

[image]

Result: deleted tagged manifest which is the only one present:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Manual

The Azure Container Registry [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge#use-the-purge-command) states (bold+ italic emphasis mine)

---

`acr purge` supports several optional parameters. [..]

**--untagged** - Specifies that  ***all [...] untagged manifests [...] are deleted***. This parameter also deletes untagged manifests  ***in addition to tags that are already being deleted***.

---

So, with `--filter` and `--ago`, you can select some manifests, and *additionally* untagged manifests are removed. The `--untagged` option does not look at `--ago`.

#### Suggested solution

Using an realistically unmatchable value for `--ago` would then only remove untagged manifests.

As always, test the results with `--dry-run` first. Correlate the result with what you see listed as number of manifests in the ACR User interface or otherwise.

`acr purge --untagged --dry-run --filter '[repository-name]:.*' --ago 365000d`

#### Final Notes:

- I used `365000d`, because the year postfix (`y` in `1000y`) is not supported.
- As of writing the whole purge command is expected to be wrapped in `az acr run --cmd "<cmd>" /dev/null`, see the original question.
- I hope and suggest that the purge command will be improved to allow for separate control of untagged manifests without trickery.
- Note that `--filter` will be required and applied when `--untagged` is active, so you can limit the action to certain repository. Source: Experimentation

Comment: Command improvement issue was discussed quite a while ago at the Azure ACR github: https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `.*` as the tag filter results in the `acr` tool untagging all images (and then the `--untagged` removes all of the freshly untagged images). If you just want to removed untagged images, specify a non-existing tag in the `--filter` parameter, to keep that from untagging any additional images.

E.g.

```bash
acr purge --filter '[repository-name]:fake-tag' --untagged --ago 1m
```

(The `az acr run` variant should work as well, I'm not particularly sure why it is used)